# Ubuntu 17.10 Touchpad: two-finger-tap action

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, 17.10

Hi i just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and was configuring it so that i 'can work' with it.

and i stumbled over the touchpad configuration.

**my touchpad has two hardware buttons for left and right click (which i both use). and i used two-finger-tap always as action for a middle mousebutton click. is this anyhow possible?**

On previous versions i could easily use: `synclient TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2`

but this seems not possible anymore.

---

```
$ xinput                                                                 

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:13                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

this told me that wayland is now responsible for my touch settings.

first i tried: `xinput set-button-map xwayland-pointer:13 1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

while this allowes me to use two-finger-tap for a middle mouse button click, it also changes my `right-touchpad-button` to a `middle mouse button` instead of a `right mouse button`.

---

edit 1: so i stumbled across this: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90204

is this the last word? "wontfix"? for apparently no reason at all!?

---

so... is there any way to make my desired configuration somehow possible?

(I'm aware that i could probably use the fallback Xorg login, but then i'll have this problem when 18.04 arrives)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to re-implement your synaptics touchpad configuration for libinput. The [Arch wiki has a great page on Libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) that explains how configure libinput, both as runtime for testing, and also for persistent configuration.